# What are the differences between the gaslanes in Chainlink VRFv2?

Tags: chainlink, vrf, avax

I'm looking to implement Chainlink VRF on the Avalanche Chain, and I have an issue estimating the gasLane. On chainlink docs, they have 3 tiers:

- 200 gwei Key Hash
- 500 gwei Key Hash
- 1000 gwei Key Hash

Which one to choose? What are the differences?

Additionally, GWEI is irrevelant in avalanche, gas is calculated in nAvax as 1 nAVAX is equal to 0.000000001 AVAX

Comment: Weis are interchangeable to whatever is the Ethereum EVM clone chain native token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/get-a-random-number/#:%7E:text=Key%20Hash):

> bytes32 keyHash: The gas lane key hash value, which is the maximum gas price you are willing to pay for a request in wei. It functions as an ID of the off-chain VRF job that runs in response to requests.

So the `200 gwei` keyhash means that if your `fulfillRandomWords` function has a gas price more than `200 gwei` the chainlink node will not call it.

Similarly, the `500` gwei keyhash means if calling the `fulfillRandomWords` function has a gas price over `500 gwei`, it will not be called.

With Avalanche or other non-ETH EVM chains, GWEI & WEI are the same, just with the native token of that chain.

For example

- 1 ETH = 1000000000000000000 WEI
- 1 AVA = 1000000000000000000 WEI
- 1 ETH = 1000000000 GWEI
- 1 AVA = 1000000000 GWEI (or nAVAX)

The naming isn't really important. So just translate GWEI -> Whatever native currency you're using. GWEI == nAVAX